# python : simulate an array with different length

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, simulation

See the code. I am trying to simulate an array called 'xx'. Following the code, I am simulating each component in the matrix one by one. This is super time-consuming when M and N are very large. The reason why I do this is because in the function 'func', for each column data, the 'samplesize 'is different. Is there any faster way to generate this numpy array please? Thank you.

```
import numpy as np

def func ( x , n):
    samplesize  = np.random.poisson(x)
    return np.random.uniform(0,  2, samplesize)

def singlerow(x, n ,N):
    rowdata = np.zeros(N)
    rowdata[0] = 0
    for i in range(1, N):
        rowdata[i] = rowdata[i-1] + np.sum(func(x, n))
    return rowdata

def simulatematrix( x,n ,M, N):
    result = np.zeros((M,N))
    for m in range(M):
        result[m] = singlerow(x,n, N)
    return result

M = 100
N = 10

xx = simulatematrix(40, 10, M, N)
```

Comment: Can you please say a little more about how "xx" is to be used?   Unless there's some shortcut we can glean from that information, I fear this is just going to be O(M*N), as you've coded it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This 'xx' is used for another project.  I am afraid that is all the info for this question.

Comment: The syntax error is caused by missing ) in the previous line(s).  But also your `use of `fromfunction` is wrong.  It is not an iterator.  The function must be array "friendly", accepting the whole mesh as produced by `np.indices`.  You probably don't want/need to use it.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I have no idea what you are talking about. I didn't not see any syntax error when I run my code.